# Rename [podcasts-app] → [podcasts.app] for consistency

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

**I propose renaming the tag [podcasts-app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/podcasts-app) to [podcasts.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/podcasts.app) for consistency with other app tags.**

The majority of tags for apps on iOS, watchOS, and macOS end in `.app` to specify it is about the platform-specific app, rather than the service itself. For example:

[activity.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/activity.app), [apple-watch.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch.app), [contacts.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contacts.app), [mail.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail.app), [music.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music.app),  [notes.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notes.app), [photos.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos.app).

---

See also: *[Rename [terminal] to [terminal.app] to make it clear the tag is for the macOS app](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2945/72620)*

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. This seems to be the only tag ending in `-app` (but not anymore).